# Mac OS X thinks my “Windows” key is a “Control” key

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using a Windows keyboard—a [Poseidon Z Thermaltake](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16823162029)—on my Macbook pro. I’m trying to keep the mappings between the laptop and the keyboard the same (so <kbd>ctrl</kbd> = <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>windows</kbd> = <kbd>alt/option</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd> = <kbd>command</kbd>).  The problem is that OS X thinks that my windows key and ctrl key are the same thing.

Here is what I mean by that.  Currently, my <kbd>windows</kbd> key mimics the functionality of the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key.  So, if I change the mapping for <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key, the <kbd>windows</kbd> key also changes. For example, if I set the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key to “No Action,” the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key AND <kbd>windows</kbd> key become disabled.  Changing the <kbd>option</kbd> key mapping doesn’t affect any key on my keyboard. The only thing that affects my <kbd>windows</kbd> key mapping is the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key mapping.

I haven’t seen anybody with an issue like this.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by using a program such as Karabiner to view your keyboard mappings, to make sure that your Mac is recognising them as independent keys. If so, you can remap the Windows and Control keys separately through the program to do whatever you want. If it is not recognising them as independent keys, you may need to get proper drivers or something to make it recognise the keyboard properly.